# How to use function with variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

How to use `function` with variables in `JavaScript`:

```
function incrementValue()
{

    var date = new Date();
    var lr = "LR";
    var citycode = '<?php echo $citycode; ?>';
    var branchcode = '<?php echo $brcode; ?>';
    var Month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

    var year = ((date.getFullYear().length) === 1)? (date.getFullYear()) : 0  + (date.getFullYear() %100);
    var cdate = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('lro').value);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('lro').value = citycode + lr + year + Month +    cdate + branchcode + value;

}
```

My php file button code:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="incrementValue()" name="save123"  value="save" class="btn green">
```

I'm getting some error on script.

Comment: What are the errors that you get ?

Comment: Please show us the errors. We can't help you if you don't show us all the info.

Comment: If i'm remove the function tag the script is works fine. if i am use the script it shows nothing.

Comment: Use your browser console to find out errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If i'm remove the function tag the script is works fine. if i am use the script it shows nothing.

Putting it in a function means nothing will happen until you call the function.

You call the function when a submit button is clicked.

Clicking a submit button will also submit the form.

Submitting a form will load a new document … which will erase the DOM changes you made.

It sounds like you should be moving your logic server side.